# Efficient Enumeration of subsets of variable size

Tags: matlab, performance, combinations, enumeration, combinatorics

There are 2 variables: `i` and `j`.

`i` runs from 1 to fixed constant N. `j` runs from 1 to `M(i)`, meaning we have an array

```
M=zeros(N,1);
M=[3,2,5,4];
```

Also `S` is a set of say 10 integers. Corresponding to every `i`, I have to find all possible ways of choosing numbers from `S` up to a given max limit `M(i)`.

My code:

```
desired_enumerations={};
for i=1:N
   for j=1:M(i)
      a = combnk(S,j);
      for k=1:size(a,1)
          desired_enumerations{end+1,1}=a(k,:);
      end
   end
end
```

My question:

I want to pre-compute all possible subsets of `S` up to `max(M)` elements outside the double for loop and then use that data inside the for loops so i don't have to enumerate the subsets inside double for loop and avoid repeated calculations.

What is an efficient way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Just as a bonus if someone could also give the time-complexity of the code in big-O notation. Or i can open a new question.

Comment: in the case of M=65, and s is [100x1] vector. Do you have enough space, memory and time to compute that...?? Are you Google..? :)

Comment: Note that `M=zeros(N,1);` is useless as the next statement overwrites `M`.

Comment: the function combnk returns n!/k!(n – k)! rows. n=100, k=65, that's 1E27 rows and 65 columns. So your `a` variable requires 57.5 brontobyte. :)

Comment: I have seen some code in this fashion, namely enumerating all choose-combinations before using them one by one. And the memory management is amazing. Trust me you won't get further than 10. Along with this strong -blatant- discouragement, I strongly suggest you use the combination on-the-go, aka don't pre-calc it. You trade some CPU time for memory.

Comment: @Adiel I agree. I just randomly wrote down M to pose this question. I will not be dealing with S having more than 20 elements and max(M) will be 5 or 6.